# Labeling points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with 1 index such that certain properties are satisfied.

Tags: number-theory, natural-numbers

I have an infinite set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $\{ (n, m) \}$ where $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$. The Euclidean distance of these points to the origin is given by $\sqrt{n^2+m^2}$. My question now is, since I know that $n^2+m^2 \in \mathbb{N}$ and I know that there exists multiple bijections between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^2$. Is it possible to label this set of points by a single natural number, $k$, such that

1. $\sqrt{k} = \sqrt{n^2+m^2}$
2. There is a sort of bijection between using the label $k$ and the $(n, m)$ coordinates meaning: i) given a $k$, you can find associated $(n, m)$ and the same in reverse
   ii) $k$ takes on all values in $\mathbb{N}$

Thanks for the help and if something is not clear let me know.

Comment: Since $\sqrt{k^2}=k\in\Bbb N$ and since $\sqrt{m^2+n^2}$ isn't always an integer, the answer is negative.

Comment: Oh my bad it should have been $\sqrt{k}$, I edited it now.

Comment: There's a bijection between *sets* of ordered pairs and $k$, but not between individual points and $k$. For instance, $k=5$ gives $(m,n) \in \{(0,\pm 5), (\pm 3,\pm 4), (\pm 4,\pm 3), (\pm 5, 0)\}$. That's a bijection, but I can't tell if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: I was looking for one between individual points and $k$. However for my application thinking in terms of the sets might work. Thanks!